# How to solve this differential equation with given data?

Tags: calculus

We are given a differentiable function $f$ satisfying the following conditions: 
$$
\begin{split}
f(2x)&=2\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}\\
f'(0)&=1
\end{split}.
$$ 
By using these conditions, we should be able to find the area bounded by $y=f(x)$ and $x$ axis, but how can we do this?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is: differentiating the equation we get $f'(2x)=\operatorname{e}^{-x}(f(x)-f'(x))$. Is there a way to use this result for evaluation of $\int_0^1 f(x) \operatorname d x$? Maybe with some integration by parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=xe^{-x} \rightarrow f(2x)=2xe^{-2x}$ which is equal to $2 \times f(x) \times e^{-x}$. $f'(x)=e^{-x}-xe^{-x} \rightarrow f'(0)=1$

So this function satisfies the conditions. We can find the area by taking integral.

Comment: any other way where you find out the function by calculating it and not assuming it?thanks anyways